# Sieve of Eratosthenes using a bit array

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes, bitarray

I have a bit array `prime[]`of `unsigned int`. I wish to implement a Sieve of Eratosthenes using this array, by having each bit represent a number `n`. That is, given `n`, the array element that holds the bit that corresponds to `n` would be `prime[n/32]` and the specific bit would be in position `n%32`.

My `testBitIs0(int n)` function returns 1 when the number is prime (if its bit == 0), otherwise 0:

```
return ( (prime[n/32] & (1 << (n%32) )) != 0);
```

My `setBit(int n)` function simply sets the bit to 1 at the corresponding position:

```
int i = n/32;
int pos = n%32;
unsigned int flag = 1;
flag = flag << pos;
prime[i] = prime[i] | flag;
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I call `setBit` with multiples of a prime number, I don't think it sets the bit correctly. When I call `setBit` with multiples of a prime number (such as 4, 6, 8, etc. for the number 2) the next time I run this line:

```
if(testBitIs0(i)) { ... }
```

With `i = 4/6/8/etc` it will still return 1 when it should return 0.
Can someone please check my code to make sure I am implementing this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Why does `testBitIs0` check if the bit is *not* zero?

Comment: Please post a complete example...

Comment: Hang on, you said `testBitIs0` returns 1 when the number is prime (if its bit == 0), but in the implementation you compare against false instead of true. You can just have `testBitIs0` be `return !(prime[n/32] & (1 << (n%32)))`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it does what you're after.  There's a bit array and some bit twiddling functions too.

http://bcu.copsewood.net/dsalg/bitwise/bitwise.html